# Numeração de linhas em códigos grandes

Tags: novo-recurso, status-recusado

Provavelmente já sugeriram isso... mas seria interessante a opção numeração de linhas em códigos extensos, para melhor facilidade e certeza na explicação de respostas sobre códigos de outras pessoas.

Comment: A questão deveria ser: por quê códigos grandes estão sendo postados? O StackOverflow preza pelo [mcve](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) e snippets.

Comment: Além de concordar com o comentário acima, tb tem o fato de que basta você escrever por extenso o que está explicando. Fica inclusive mais fácil para quem está lendo a resposta não ter que ficar procurando na pergunta qual é a linha que a resposta está se referindo.

Comment: Eu concordo que códigos grandes são em geral ruins. Mas, em alguns casos, eles podem ser necessários. De cabeça eu só consigo imaginar um exemplo de code-golf (que está aparentemente sendo aceito pela comunidade). Agora, sendo o código grande ou não, se o recurso de linhas existisse seria muito mais fácil explicar certas partes do código referindo às linhas do que replicando-as no texto. Ao menos na minha opinião. :)

Comment: @LuizVieira talvez você ou o autor poderiam adicionar um exemplo real de onde ele seria útil, pois até o momento achei desnecessário.

Comment: @Math Boa ideia. Vou procurar ou pensar a respeito. Se encontrar algo, eu posto por aqui. :)

Comment: @Math Postei uma resposta com o que eu achei de exemplos potenciais.

Comment: Seria bom também ouvir argumentos *contra* o recurso. Já que a pergunta tem alguns votos negativos, talvez eles se devam à mais do que preferência. :)

Comment: @LuizVieira a pergunta tem 3 votos negativos e dois argumentos contra, já é alguma coisa. Vou ler sua resposta logo mais e daí posso atualizar minha opinião.

Comment: O @Kyllopardiun na verdade não fez um argumento contra, apenas apontou outra discussão que julgou mais relevante. E o seu argumento, Math, me parece na verdade mais a favor do que contra a numeração de linhas. Porque fica justamente mais fácil achar sem ter que ficar procurando na pergunta. :)

Comment: Adicionei uma resposta abaixo com meu exemplo.

Comment: Relacionada : [why there are no line numbers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7119/why-are-there-no-line-numbers-in-the-code-listings). E pelo que vi lá, não será implementado.

Comment: @Kyllopardiun Lá tem um bom argumento contra na resposta mais votada: "One very important drawback that hasn't been mentioned is that editing a post would potentially invalidate all the existing answers and comments referring to a specific line number in a previous revision."

Comment: Eu sei que não vai acontecer mas gostaria de ter esse recurso. O mau uso não deve ser usado para justificar a não existência dele. Não é para ter numeração por default mas seria útil. Como não vai rolar, quando a numeração for necessária podemos colar o código como imagem. Isso é usar o recursos errado, mas é a solução que a SE nos deixa.

Answer (score 2):

### Cenários de exemplo em que esse recurso pode ser útil

**1. Longa explicação envolvendo pedaços de código**

[Nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11378/%C3%89-correto-dar-maior-prefer%C3%AAncia-a-composi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-que-heran%C3%A7a/11380#11380), a respeito da preferência por herança ou composição, o autor fornece uma explicação bastante didática envolvendo diversos pedaços de código. Em momentos em que sua explicação trata de aspectos importantes do argumento, ele usa marcações de código para apontar onde isso é feito no código. Eis um exemplo:

Passagem no texto:

> [...] controla os atributos específicos do animal fazendo uso do
>   objeto anterior (pois um `Animal` é um `ObjetoPosicionado`), [...]

Referência a esse pedaço de código:

> ```
> interface ObjetoPosicionado { }
> interface Animal extends ObjetoPosicionado { }
> [...]
> ```

O raciocínio do autor da resposta faz referência àquela linha, e por isso seria potencialmente útil se ele pudesse simplesmente referenciá-la por um número ao invés de precisar repetir instruções ou palavras reservadas no texto. Além disso, do ponto de vista de leitores com menos experiência, a referência a linhas do código é ainda mais didática. Eu já senti essa necessidade em [respostas como essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/11094/73), em que fiz uma explicação com *bullets* passo a passo do funcionamento de um algoritmo sugerido.

**2. Discussões a respeito de partes do código**

[Nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23093/erro-na-declara%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-relacionamento-1-para-1-no-ef-com-code-first-e-atributos) houve uma natural especulação do potencial problema do usuário feita vias comentários. Isso é bastante comum e natural, ocorrendo principalmente em casos em que pequenos erros ou inconsistências podem ser diretamente encontrados no código. Pela inexistência de indicações de linhas, os comentadores comumente replicam passagens do código ou indicam-nas textualmente. Por exemplo:

> Cara, acho que nao precisa declarar o UsuarioId duas vezes como você
>   ta fazendo... Tira aquela anotação de ForeignKey de Usuario pra ver se
>   funciona. Talvez seja isso. –  Érik Thiago 1/07 às 14:44

A passagem "Tira aquela anotação de ForeignKey [...]" seria bem mais clara se pudesse ser indicada com uma linha numérica.

### Enfim

Eu acho que é possível achar outros exemplos em que o uso de linhas seria potencialmente útil. Mas admito que tudo isso é discutível. Os próprios envolvidos nos exemplos acima *não demonstraram sentir* falta do recurso. Mesmo eu, que senti falta dele na minha resposta referenciada, convivi sem e não achei necessário "discutir" por aqui há época. Mas isso não quer dizer que o recurso não seria útil se existisse.

EDIÇÃO: (*Do meu ponto de vista, a inclusão de numeração de linhas em código só vai trazer benefícios.*) Preciso admitir que isso não é totalmente verdade. O @Kyllopardiun indicou o link da [discussão original no Metão](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7119/why-are-there-no-line-numbers-in-the-code-listings), onde a resposta mais aceita tem o seguinte argumento (em tradução livre):

> Uma desvantagem muito importante que não foi mencionada é que a edição
>   de uma postagem pode invalidar todas as respostas e comentários
>   referendo um número de linha específico em uma revisão anterior.
>   Blocos de código são provavelente editados mais frequentemente do que
>   qualquer outra parte de uma questão, porque as pessoas muitas vezes
>   não postam código suficiente para responder a questão de primeira. Eu
>   acredito que a conveniência inicial da numeração de linha seria
>   frequentemente prejudicada pela confusão de não saber o quanto você
>   pode confiar nas referências a ela.

Esse problema talvez fosse mais facilmente contornado pelo OP ao se preocupar com a edição do conteúdo como um todo, mas ele é realmente mais difícil no cenário 2 que eu exemplifiquei, em que existem referências às linhas em comentários.

Comment: Concordo que pode sim ter suas utilidades, mas tenho minhas dúvidas se a complexidade adicionada não acaba criando mais empecilhos do que facilidades. PS: não fui eu que dei -1, ainda posso ser convencido a mudar de opinião.

Comment: @Math Entendo. De fato, depois do argumento lá do Metão sobre a dificuldade com a edição creio que as facilidades ficam mesmo menos relevantes. Ainda assim manterei meu voto positivo porque eu particularmente gostaria de ter esse recurso disponível. :)

Answer (score 2):

Números não são tão bons assim para servir de referência porque eles mudam se alguém adicionar uma linha no início do código.

Na minha experiência, se o objetivo é referenciar linhas no código a melhor forma de fazer isso é usando comentários

```
if(){ 
    blah();  // <---- erro nessa linha
}
```

Mesmo se você não incluir nenhum texto, só de por as setas já ajuda a indicar quais são as linhas mais interessantes do seu código.

Answer (score 0):

**Segue um exemplo pessoal:**

Na resposta que eu dei a 
[essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23956/linguagem-c-n%c3%bameros-primos-em-vetores/27276#27276), seria muito mais simples, ao invés de colocar:

> Então faça isso:
>
> Recorte as linhas:
>     d=2;
>     verifica=1;
>
> E cole logo no início do for,

Eu simplesmente colocar:

Então faça isso:

> Recorte as linhas 13 e 14, e cole no início do for, linha 20.

Reconheço que talvez minha resposta foi bem mais pra "dar o peixe" do que pra "ensinar a pescar". Aceito comentários a respeito.

**Minha opinião sobre o tema:**

Fiz a sugestão para o novo recurso, por ser um auxílio, algo que ajude, facilite e evite possíveis confusões em respostas, e talvez alguns comentários desnecessários para explicações, mas não por ser uma NECESSIDADE. Consegui, e acredito que se consiga se virar muito bem no Stack Overflow sem esse recurso, caso contrário ele já teria sido implementado. Mas achei válido sugerir.

Sou um integrante novo no Stack Exchange, e, talvez por isso, e talvez também por não ser um programador muito experiente, dei falta de algo que as pessoas que estão aqui a mais tempo, e são mais experientes, não ligam.

Acredito também que, como o primeiro comentário, colocar códigos grandes, respeitando o MCVE, não deveriam acontecer com frequência, mas infelizmente eu já vi alguns assim, em perguntas sobre revisão de código e algoritmo.